# Правильный перенос текста ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, перенос

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titlelayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textColor="@color/yellowcardcolor"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/doublemenuhalflrpaddings"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/text2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:text="d sd fasddkddda d d d d asdddddd asdf f asd ads fasdf asd fsaf as dfasdf asdf asd fasd fasd fasd fasd ff asddddf asdf d d d d d ddddddddhgв "
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textColor="@color/colorblack"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/doublemenuhalftbpaddings"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/doublemenuhalflrpaddings"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/text3"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:text="text3"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textColor="@color/yellowcardcolor"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/doublemenuhalflrpaddings"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/text2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы text1 был закреплен строго в начале экрана, text3 строго в конце, а text2 был слева от text1 и переносился на следующую строку (не налегая при этом поверх text3), когда его длина больше, чем место между text1 и text3. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titlelayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textColor="@color/yellowcardcolor"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/doublemenuhalflrpaddings"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:text="d sd fasddkddda d d d d asdddddd asdf f asd ads fasdf asd fsaf as dfasdf asdf asd fasd fasd fasd fasd ff asddddf asdf d d d d d ddddddddhgв "
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textColor="@color/colorblack"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/doublemenuhalftbpaddings"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/doublemenuhalflrpaddings"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:text="text3"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textColor="@color/yellowcardcolor"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/doublemenuhalflrpaddings"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать LinearLayout с весом у каждого элемента:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="21"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="text1"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:textColor="@color/yellowcardcolor"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/doublemenuhalflrpaddings"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:text="d sd fasddkddda d d d d asdddddd asdf f asd ads fasdf asd fsaf as dfasdf asdf asd fasd fasd fasd fasd ff asddddf asdf d d d d d ddddddddhgв "
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textColor="@color/colorblack"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/doublemenuhalftbpaddings"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/doublemenuhalflrpaddings"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:text="text3"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textColor="@color/yellowcardcolor"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/doublemenuhalflrpaddings"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

это самый простой вариант как мне кажется. Можно конечно заморочиться и сделать все в constraintLayout :) но в моем варианте все будет строго фиксировано.

Comment: Тогда мне придется каждый раз подбирать веса исходя из размера контента в правом и левом полях, верно? А для этого нужен код для расчета длины поля в зависимости от наполнения. Из длины экрана надо вычитать потенциальную длину левого и правого поля с учетом всех марджинов и паддингов.

Comment: нет, вы просто можете грузить туда текст и все виджеты будут всегда занимать четко треть экрана, независимо от наполнения

Comment: В ConstraintLayout тоже есть веса, кстати: app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2".

Comment: да я знаю, но я не нашел где устанавливается общая сумма весов, поэтому решил что через linear будет проще

Comment: Я всегда без суммы весов делал. Чтобы было поровну - можно задать как 1 1 1, так и 2 2 2. И даже 0.1 0.1 0.1

Comment: мой выбор пал на linear не только из-за суммы весов, просто если делать привязку между 1 и 2 виджетами, то у 2 нужно будет марджин вероятнее всего делать слева, чтобы он не налезал на 1 и на 3 тоже, так мне кажется менее заморочено сделать можно)